# Extracting Hour from datetime difference with round off 1 - Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, automation

Is there an option to extract time difference in hours with one decimal(8.4,9.2).When i use

```
(arm['EndTime']-arm['StartTime']).astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

The result is 8.0 instead of 8.4,  and 9 instead of 9.2
The result automatically round off's to 0...
I tried using the following code

```
(arm['EndTime']-arm['StartTime']).astype('timedelta64[h]').round(1)
```

But it yielded the same result.

Comment: get the delta in seconds, divide by 3600 and round the result

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) with divide by `3600` by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) with [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
(arm['EndTime']-arm['StartTime']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600).round(1)
```